# How do black holes lose their mass?

Tags: black-hole

As I was searching the answer to 'What comes after Black Holes', I found these two threads talking about the same thing

[Do black holes die?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/do-black-holes-die)

[Can a black hole reach a limit where it can no longer attract more matter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/can-a-black-hole-reach-a-limit-where-it-can-no-longer-attract-more-matter)

The answers here mention that Black holes do die but with time and they "**evaporate**"

What do you mean by **Evaporation of a Black Hole**?

**How do these black holes lose their mass?**

Comment: Also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/what-does-it-mean-for-a-black-hole-to-evaporate

Answer (score 1):

"Black holes evaporate with time" means they lose mass and energy with time. This phenomenon is termed as Hawking radiation (named after Prof. Stephen Hawking who gave the theory) or simply black hole evaporation. According to him when a particle or antiparticle pop into existence at the event horizon instead of annihilating each other as they are supposed to, one of the the two will fall in the black hole and other will escape. Some of the mass inside the black hole is converted into energy which later converts into particles ( at the event horizon in this case)
The black hole loses energy/mass in form of  particle ( mass and energy are equivalent)

Comment: How do they lose mass?

Comment: i edited the answer